# Fill master and detail view in full screen mode of iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, master-detail

I am using Master-Detail Application template, in my iPad application.
I have master-view that contains list of videos. When selecting any list item, it starts playing video of that item on the detail-view.
I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play the videos. 
If I press full screen icon, the player should fill the entire screen (master-view as well as detail-view, not just detail-view). 
How could I do this? Please help!

Comment: When you select on e Video, your Master view must b removed.. Right?
So its obvious to display fullscreen on entire screen..

Comment: @Myaaoonn this is not a proper solution for remove master View

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted? Seems like a legitimate question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can Hide or show `MasterViewcontroller` By using Delegate of `UISplitViewController`

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem;

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc;
```

**UPDATE:-**

Example Code:-

set One `BOOL` value in you **DetailViewController.h** class

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL  IShide;
```

and Do this Following Method into you **.M** class

```
-(void)hideMaster:(id)hideState
{

    _IShide=!self.IShide;
    [self.splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = nil;
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;

    [self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication    sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];

 //also put your `MPMoviePlayerController` Fullscreen Method here
}

#pragma mark - Split view

-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return self.IShide;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    UIBarButtonItem *Fullscreen = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"FullScreen", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(hideMaster:)];
     [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:Fullscreen animated:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

while you click on the Fullscreen Event of you `MPMoviePlayerController` call this Delegate with this Event as par you hide and show MasterViewController.

**Code OUTPUT is**

[image]

Comment: This causes some strange issues in iOS8 once you rotate the device to portrait.